# Selenium test is taking abnormally long

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium test, where part of the function reads:

```
try {
     System.out.println("1.d.i");
     Boolean tosDisplayed = driver.findElements(By.id("tos-acceptance")).size()<0; 

     System.out.println("1.d.ii");                      
     if(tosDisplayed){
          SureClick(By.id("tos-acceptance"));
          SureClick(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/button[1]"));
     }
}
```

I get the "1.d.i" printed, and then the WebDriver just hangs there for almost 5 minutes before moving on to the rest of the function. However, if I comment out the Boolean tosDisplayed declaration, it also prints "1.d.ii" before hanging on the rest of the code. Eventually, the test completes, but it is taking way too long. Is something wrong with my WebDriver? Please let me know if there are any more details I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use Logger.
e.g. 

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class QCEditTestCaseTest extends  BaseSeleniumTest {


            private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QCEditTestCaseTest.class);
            @Test
            public void prerequisitesFilling(){

            //blablabla
            // your code here
            //blablabla
             log.info(any info);
//             log.error(any errors catched by try-catch block);
            }
        }
```

Hope this be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the following line is causing you problems:

```
Boolean tosDisplayed = driver.findElements(By.id("tos-acceptance")).size()<0;
```

A list (which is what driver.findElements() returns) will never have a size of less than 0.

If you comment our the Boolean definition when you reach the if statement the boolean doesn't exist so I would expect it to blow up at that point.

I don't know what SureClick does so I couldn't tell you why things are slow if you are getting slow down inside that method as well, you would have to provide the code for it to get any more help.